# Filter dependency lookup for Repository in Gradle

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle, repository

I have defined 2 Repos in my Gradle build:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url "http://someurl:8081/nexus/content/repositories/myrepo" }
}
```

Now I just want to resolve specific artifacts (my project-internal groupId) via mavenLocal, all other dependencies shoud get looked up via the maven repo.

My Idea was to do something like

```
mavenLocal{
    addFilter('group') {artifact, file ->
            artifact.group == 'my.group'
        }
}
```

but it's not working. Is there a way to intercept dependency lookup for the local maven repository?

Note: I've seen [How to configure gradle to use a local repository only for certain dependency groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016226/how-to-configure-gradle-to-use-a-local-repository-only-for-certain-dependency-gr) , but the solution provided is not satisfactory for me.

As discussed here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/problem_mixing_gradle_and_maven_repositories I need the maven local repo to interchange between maven and gradle builds

EDIT: According to Peter Niederwisers Answer, "There isn't currently a finer-grained way to control this." (Current version: 1.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency is searched for in all repositories, in the repositories' declared order. The search stops once the dependency has been successfully resolved. There isn't currently a finer-grained way to control this.

If you absolutely need a workaround, you could try to come up with a solution based on spreading dependency declarations over multiple projects (which can have different repositories).

Comment: "There isn't currently a finer-grained way to control this." Sad story. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

an update to who is out on [as of gradle 5.1](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/release-notes.html#repository-to-dependency-matching)+: we now have (incubating) [Declaring a repository filter](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#declaring_a_repository_filter)

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal{
    content {
       includeGroup "my.group"
    }
  }
}
```